# Insert text content into a blob in DB2 database using a simple SQL query

Tags: sql, insert, db2, blob

I am having trouble inserting in a BLOB field some text content (in fact it's an XML, I know there are field-types more suited than BLOB for this type of content, but I simply can't change it).

I have the necessity of inserting some values using simple SQL queries, I am using this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO XXX.MYTABLE (MY_KEY, MY_VALUE) VALUES(0, CAST('<some xml content here/>' AS BLOB) );
```

The command is executed, but it stores in the database some application/octet-stream content that converted back to text appears like

> LÓ…££…™?çÔÓ£…¢£–n%L£‰—–É•„‰™‰©©–nÁLa£‰—–É•„‰™‰©©–n%L¢?“¤£‰nâ—…££K“…La¢?“¤£‰n%L–‡‡…££–nÓ…££…

I guess it is an encoding issue, but the documentation says "BLOB does not have  any Coded Character Set Identifier (CCSID) associated with the field", so I do not know how to work around this issue.

The DBMS is DB2 10.1

Comment: I don't know db2, but shouldn't it be clob instead of blob? (Or nclob)

Comment: Yeah, of course. And to be honest it does exist a field type specific for xml. But as I said in the question, unfortunately I can't change it.

Comment: How do you select the content back that produced the shown output?

Comment: @data_henrik I retrieved the "corrupted" text both from a Java Enterprise application and from a graphic database tool (DBVisualizer)

Comment: @alessop86: Yup, but using what query? Any casts involved? On the way in the data was converted from string to binary. Now on the way back out it should be string again.

Comment: @data_henrik Inside the application the data are retrieved via a resultSet.getBlob(index).getBinaryStream(). On the gui DB tool I have no idea.

Anyway while the preexisting BLOB are correctly displayed on DB GUI tool and correctly read from the application, the new blob inserted through my query display a totally messed up encoding, and I was wondering if was possible to tweak the query in order to avoid this

Comment: Cross-posted at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115886/insert-string-content-into-a-blob-in-db2-database-using-a-simple-sql-query

Comment: @mustaccio I was not sure which was the most appropriated website

Comment: Guess what happens when I run the gibberish in an EBCDIC to ASCII Converter ... . ..  `<LetterXMLtesto>
<tipoIndirizzo>A</tipoIndirizzo>
<sluti>Spett.le</sluti>
<oggetto>Lette`    The `CAST AS BLOB` is storing the XML in UTF/ASCII but you're fetching data in EBCDIC. Try to CAST the BLOB back into an XML type when doing SELECT